# Matching vectors from one list, to data frames in another list by length

Tags: r

I have two lists: one contains multiple data frame with different length. For each length I have a corresponding array in a list of arrays and now I want to apply these arrays as colnames to the vector of the same length.

```
for (i in 1:10){
assign(paste0("var",i), c(1:10))
}

df1 <- data.frame(var1,var2)
df2 <- data.frame(var3,var4,var5)
df3 <- data.frame(var6,var7,var8,var9)
df4 <- data.frame(var10)
df5 <- data.frame(var1,var2)
df6 <- data.frame(var3,var4,var5)
df7 <- data.frame(var6,var7,var8,var9)
df8 <- data.frame(var10)

my.list <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)

names1 <- c("aa","bb")
names2 <- c("cc","dd","ee")
names3 <- c("ff","gg","hh","ii")
names4 <- c("jj")

my.list.names <- list(names1,names2,names3,names4)

for (i in 1:length(my.list)){
    if (length(my.list[[i]]) == length(my.list.names))
    colnames(my.list[[i]]) <- my.list.names
}
```

I can see why my solution doesn't really work. I have to not only go over each data frame in my.list but also over each possible vector from my.list.names and then see if they match.

I can't really wrap my head around this "loop inside a loop thing". I've tried more elegant solutions with apply, too. But I end up at the same point. Also there seems to be another if condition missing at the end, but it doesn't really seem right to specify again what I wrote as if statement one line earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close – you just need an inner loop to check the length of the column names and assign them if they match the length (number of columns) in the data frame:

```
for (i in seq_along(my.list)){
  for (cols in my.list.names){
    if(length(my.list[[i]]) == length(cols)) {
      names(my.list[[i]]) <- cols
    }
  }
}
```

(Also, take care with your overall approach – it assumes that there's only one vector within `my.list.names` of a given length, and that at least one vector of column names exists for each data frame of a given length.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no gaps in the number of column name vectors (ie, not something like 1 varname, 2 varnames, 3 varnames,4 varnames, 6 varnames), which holds in the example, the solution below should do the trick:

```
# put names into a list, assumes no other objects with "names" in their name
namesList <- mget(ls(pattern="names"))
# sort names by length, this assumes no gaps in column count
namesList <- namesList[order(lengths(namesList))]

# add names to list of data.frames
my.list <- lapply(my.list, function(i) setNames(i, namesList[[length(i)]]))
```

The first element of the list is

```
my.list[[1]]
   aa bb
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```